# Devise Update method does not have ID in route

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise, routes, updates

I have two models using Devise 3.  My edit and update routes do not have the /:id that I would expect and it is causing me to receive a bad PUT requestion as you can see below.

```
Started PUT "/users.user" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-06-11 11:11:46 -0400
Processing by RegistrationsController#update as 

Completed 406 Not Acceptable in 4894.6ms (ActiveRecord: 2.4ms)
```

Here are the routes

```
               new_user_session GET        /users/sign_in(.:format)                           sessions#new
                   user_session POST       /users/sign_in(.:format)                           sessions#create
           destroy_user_session DELETE     /users/sign_out(.:format)                          sessions#destroy
                  user_password POST       /users/password(.:format)                          passwords#create
              new_user_password GET        /users/password/new(.:format)                      passwords#new
             edit_user_password GET        /users/password/edit(.:format)                     passwords#edit
                                PUT        /users/password(.:format)                          passwords#update
       cancel_user_registration GET        /users/cancel(.:format)                            devise/registrations#cancel
              user_registration POST       /users(.:format)                                   devise/registrations#create
          new_user_registration GET        /users/sign_up(.:format)                           devise/registrations#new
         edit_user_registration GET        /users/edit(.:format)                              devise/registrations#edit
                                PUT        /users(.:format)                                   devise/registrations#update
                                DELETE     /users(.:format)                                   devise/registrations#destroy
```

This is what my routes.rb looks like

```
  devise_for :users, :controllers => { :confirmations => "confirmations", registrations: "registrations", session: "sessions", passwords: "passwords" } 

  devise_scope :user do
    authenticated :user do
      root :to => 'appointments#index', as: :user_authenticated_root
      get "/appointments", to: "appointments#index", as: :appointments
    end
    unauthenticated :user do
      root :to => 'devise/registrations#new', as: :unauthenticated_root
    end   
    match '/join' => 'devise/registrations#new'
  end
```

My form is

```
<%= simple_form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => user_registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_notification %>
```

What am I missing to fix the routes to say /users/:id(.:format), etc ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this should do it:

```
<%= simple_form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name), html: { method: :put }) do |f| %>
```